# Autocomplete widget - save id of suggested and accepted value

Tags: ajax, entities

I'm writing a custom text field and widget module with ajax autocomplete from scratch. I want the lookup to work on one column, but I want another column's value (the looked-up item's id) to be saved as the field value in the node.

So, for example, user types for example `Sams`, they accept suggestion `Samsung`, but Drupal save its database identifier, say `145`.

Conversely, when opening the node for editing, the saved value of `145` should be again looked up, converted and displayed as `Samsung`.

What is the key to get it working the Drupal way?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Entity](http://drupal.org/project/entity) and [Entity Reference](http://drupal.org/project/entityreference) modules to create the link between the two items, using this method means your selections will be available to other modules such as Views, Rules, etc.